# java program : calculate the average?

Tags: java

I'm creating a java program, which allows me to calculate the average number of votes entered by me, and when I finally enter a negative number the program stops. The program works fine but there is a section of the program that is not shown.

Here is the program :

```
 public static void main (String[] args) {

    System.out.println("This program calculate the average of your votes");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer;

    do {
        int sum = 0, myVotes=0;
        System.out.println("Enter your votes and at the end a negative number");
        boolean average = true;

        while(average ) {
            int votes = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (votes >0) {
                sum = sum + votes;
                myVotes++;
            } else if (myVotes>0){
                System.out.println("The average is :" + (sum/myVotes));
            } else  if (votes<0){
                average = false;
            }               
        }
        System.out.println("Do you want to calculate another average : yes or no");
        answer = keyboard.next();
    }while(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
}
```

This is the section which is not show by the program :

**Do you want to calculate another average : yes or no;**
exc ..

Thank you all for the helping.

Comment: the program works fine, the only problem is that i can't calculate another average.

Comment: @Fubar String answer = "yes" , isn't this the problem

Comment: It must never hit `else  if (votes<0){` and therefore the inner `while` loop never ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in your `if-else` logic. Remove `if (myVotes>0)` and put `System.out.println("The average is :" + (sum/myVotes));` line out of `while(average )` loop:

Following is corrected code snippet:

```
do {

    int sum = 0, myVotes=0;

    System.out.println("Enter your votes and at the end a negative number");

    boolean average = true;

    while(average ) {

        int votes = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (votes >0) {
            sum = sum + votes;
            myVotes++;
        } else  if (votes<0){
            average = false;
        } 
    }

    if (myVotes != 0){//To handle divide by 0 exception
            System.out.println("The average is :" + (sum/myVotes));
    }
    System.out.println("Do you want to calculate another average : yes or no");

    answer = keyboard.next();

}while(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
```

Comment: Good! Thank you!

Comment: Consider making it the correct answer in a couple of minutes.